# Joining tables through relational table

Tags: mysql

I am looking to get a full company list with associated contacts.  Even if a company does not have any contacts they should still be included in the results.  The Company and People table are linked by a relations value table.

I have created a SQL fiddle for the scheme and would appreciate it if someone could write the query for me.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34a0a

I would see the result look like:

```
Company Name 1 | Person Number 1 <br>
Company Name 1 | Person Number 2 <br>
Company Name 2 | Person Number 3 <br>
Company Name 2 | Person Number 4 <br>
Company Name 2 | Person Number 5 <br>
Company Name 2 | Person Number 6 <br>
Company Name 3 | NULL <br>
```

Comment: If you want to give it a shot, you can use a `JOIN`. Since you want to include rows in Table1 even if they do not have an entry in Table2, you should consider using a `LEFT JOIN`. There are a lot of examples online.

Comment: I did the following but then I don't the company withe the NULL people.  


    `SELECT c.companyname, p.firstname. p.lastname FROM companies c 
    FROM companies c<
    LEFT JOIN relations rv ON rv.parentrecordid = c.id
    LEFT JOIN people p ON p.id = rv.childrecordid
    AND rv.parentmodule = 'companies' AND rv.childmodule = 'people'`

Comment: Good attempt! This query works: `SELECT
 c.companyname, 
 p_r.firstname, 
 p_r.lastname 
FROM companies c
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT r.parentrecordid, p.firstname, p.lastname FROM relations r INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = r.childrecordid AND r.childmodule = 'people') p_r
ON p_r.parentrecordid = c.id;`

Comment: The reason your attempt didn't work is that you are putting some join criteria in the overall where conditions. If you move them to the ON conditions for the join to relations it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this result with two [joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) - one to your relations table, then another to your persons table. If you use a [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), the link will not be forced, so the company without a person/relation will still be returned but with null as the person result:

```
SELECT
  C.*,
  P.*
FROM 
  companies C

LEFT JOIN
  relations R
ON (R.parentmodule = 'companies' AND R.parentrecordid = C.id)

LEFT JOIN
  people P
ON (R.childmodule = 'people' AND R.childrecordid = P.id)
```

[**Output**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34a0a/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

The following query gets the desired output. Since an inner join is used between two tables, it should be slightly faster.

```
SELECT  
    c.companyname,      
    p_r.firstname,      
    p_r.lastname  
FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT 
        r.parentrecordid, 
        p.firstname, 
        p.lastname 
    FROM relations r 
    INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = r.childrecordid AND r.childmodule = 'people'
    ) p_r 
ON p_r.parentrecordid = c.id;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34a0a/9)</kbd>